# How to use strtok()

Tags: c, printf, token, strtok

I'm writing a C program to study the usage of function `strtok()`. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    char abc[100] = "ls &";
    char *tok;

    tok = strtok(abc, " ");
    while (tok != NULL) {
        printf("%s", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n%s", tok);
    return 0;
}
```

It is printing the following output:

```
ls&




(null)
```

But I want it to print `&` at the second `printf` statement. How do I do it? I need this part for my homework project.

Comment: Your `while` loop continues until `tok` is `NULL`, right? So in the second `printf` statement, `tok` is `NULL`. Is that surprising?

Comment: Add a newline to the first printf()

Comment: And if you need help with `strtok()` you can always [consult the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: @rici Yeah it is printing NULL. How to I make it to print '&' instead?

Comment: @user2201650: How many times do you think the loop executes? What do you think it prints the first time?

Comment: Why do you even *have* the followup `printf()` ? And since you wrote this, what do you think `printf("\n\n\n\n\n%s", NULL);` will do, since you're *guaranteed* that will be what is executed? Get rid of the second `printf` and just print each token until there are no more.

Comment: @rici I think it executes thrice. The 1st time it prints 'ls'.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, but I want the tok variable to take '&' at the end and print it outside the while loop.

Comment: You need to exit the loop if `strcmp(tok, "&") == 0`. If you wait until `tok == NULL`, then the second printf doesn't have anything to print.

Comment: @Barmar, got it! THank you so much for the answer. I did the strcmp() and it worked! :) Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 8):

1. Make sure you can identify the limits of what you print when you're printing.
2. Output newlines at the end of printed messages; the information is more likely to appear in a timely manner if you do that.
3. Don't print NULL pointers as strings; not all versions of `printf()` will behave nicely — some of them dump core.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char abc[] = "ls &";
    char *tok;
    char *ptr = abc;

    while ((tok = strtok(ptr, " ")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("<<%s>>\n", tok);
        ptr = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or (optimized, courtesy of [self.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327831/self)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char abc[] = "ls &";
    char *tok = abc;

    while ((tok = strtok(tok, " ")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("<<%s>>\n", tok);
        tok = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
<<ls>>
<<&>>
```

You can choose your own marker characters, but when not messing with XML or HTML, I find the double angle brackets reasonably good for the job.

You can also use your loop structure at the cost of writing a second call to `strtok()` (which is a minimal cost, but might be argued to violate the DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char abc[] = "ls &";
    char *tok = strtok(abc, " ");

    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        printf("<<%s>>\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Same output.

---

#### Revised requirement

> I would like to add a `printf()` statement outside the `while` loop and print '`&`' outside. I need it since I want to compare it later with another variable in the program. Is there any way to do so?

Yes, there is usually a way to do almost anything.  This seems to work.  It also works sanely if there are more tokens to parse, or if there's only the `&` to parse, or if there are no tokens. Clearly, the body of the outer loop could be made into a function if you so wished; it would be sensible to do so, even.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char tests[][16] =
    {
        "ls -l -s &",
        "ls &",
        "&",
        "    ",
        ""
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(tests)/sizeof(tests[0]); i++)
    {
        printf("Initially: <<%s>>\n", tests[i]);
        char *tok1 = strtok(tests[i], " ");
        char *tok;

        while ((tok = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
        {
            printf("Loop body: <<%s>>\n", tok1);
            tok1 = tok;
        }
        if (tok1 != NULL)
            printf("Post loop: <<%s>>\n", tok1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Initially: <<ls -l -s &>>
Loop body: <<ls>>
Loop body: <<-l>>
Loop body: <<-s>>
Post loop: <<&>>
Initially: <<ls &>>
Loop body: <<ls>>
Post loop: <<&>>
Initially: <<&>>
Post loop: <<&>>
Initially: <<    >>
Initially: <<>>
```

Note how the markers pay for themselves in the last two examples.  You couldn't tell those apart without the markers.

Comment: I would like to add a printf statement outside the while loop and print '&' outside. I need it since I want to compare it later with another variable in the program. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Well, I suppose you can do it; most things _can_ be done.  Are you sure it is worth it?  Give me a few minutes while I think about it.  It is not … an obvious requirement … shall we say.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Or without the extra variable and strtok http://pastebin.com/4xHG9yGX

Comment: @self. I just looked at your pasted code; you're right, it can be made slicker.  I've done that in the past; I'd forgotten this time around.

Answer (score 0):

you should write sth like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main();
{
char string[] = "ls &"; //you should not write 100, cuz you waste memory
char *pointer;

pointer = strtok(string, " "); //skip only spaces
while(pointer != NULL)
   {
      printf("%s\n", pointer);
      pointer = strtok(string, " ");
   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: After the first call to `strtok()`, you must use `NULL` as the first argument to indicate that you are continuing where the previous call left off.

Comment: This code is buggy, you should replace strtok first value inside the while loop to NULL