# Get initial postion of word in a text

Tags: c

I need get position of word in text, but I can't convert a pointer with char *text to char text[] to compare each character.

I am trying to find the location of the first substring in a text that matches a particular word.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int searchWord(char *word, char *text);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,searchString;
    if (!(argc>2)) {
        printf("Need 2 args");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("aaa %d\n" ,searchWord(argv[1],argv[2]));

    return 0;
}

int searchWord(char *word, char *text) // I need use that function to search.
{
    printf("\n\n%s\n\n",&word[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). End every `printf` format string with `\n` or call `fflush`. Use the debugger `gdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that *text* is composed of words separated by spaces, you can consider tokenizing *text*, and then iterating through the tokens to see if they match *word*. Try making use of strtok(), and there is a lot of documentation online for how to use the function.

I found a relevant question on how to use strtok here: [how to use strtok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927793/how-to-use-strtok).

You can try to find the position this way:

```
int search(char * word, char * text, unsigned int length) {
    char * token = strtok(text, " ");
    int position = 0;

    while (token != NULL) {
        // if word matches the token, we found our word
        if (! strncmp(word, token, length)) {
            return position;
        } else {
            position += (strlen(token) + 1);
            // get the next token from the text
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    // didn't find it
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I can tokenize using strtok but how i can get position of word ?

Comment: You need to keep track of where you are in the text string, I've edited to show a way you might do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem with char* and char[] conversion, it is a problem with converting char* to int since argv[] is an array of an array of character.

Try this -- it uses pointer arithmetic and probably work:

```
int SearchWord( char *word, char *text, unsigned int length ) {
  unsigned int i = 0, d = 0, x = 0;
  x = strlen( text );
  // Keep looping til we reach less than total length
  for (; i <= ( x - length ); i++) {
    if (strncmp( text, word, length ) == 0) {
      d = i;
      break;
    }
    else {
      // Moving 1 character position
      text++;
    }
  }
  // Check if no match was found
  if (i == (x - length) {
    return -1;
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= d; i++) {
    // Revert the text
    text--;
  }
  return d;
}
```

Comment: @BrunoNovais - I've updated my post; you can pass strlen( word ) as argument for length.

Comment: strcmpn ->  strncmp   ? in c ?

Comment: oops, yes thats what i meant

Comment: i cant check that solution now..
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strncmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:209
209 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S: [Message about file not found in portuguese]

Comment: What line of my example?

Comment: is about  strncmp.. i dont know if is my libs.. or not..
https://imgur.com/VireagA

Comment: Thnkx for your edit in my question.. I found a answer about my problem.
http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/c-program-to-find-substring-of-string.html