# Analyzing Strings with sscanf

Tags: c

I need to analyze a string previous reader with fgets,

then I have a row from:

```
name age steps\n
mario 10 1 2 3 4\n
joe   15 3 5\n
max   20 9 3 2 4 5\n
```

there are a variable number of steps for each column,
then I can read name and age with

```
 sscanf(mystring, "%s %d", name, &age);
```

after this I have a for cycle for read all steps

```
   int step[20];
   int index=0;
   while(sscanf(mystring,"%d", &step[index++])>0);
```

but this cycle never ends populating all array data with the age column.

Comment: I guess the `while` loop will end because it will rrad the name and fail to interpret it as number. Please post [mcve].

Comment: You read the same string over and over.... what did you expect

Comment: You are always scanning the same string, you would need to advance the string handed to `sscanf`; just use `strtok` as shown in the answer from terence hill.

Comment: "i need to analyze a string"  --> This often leads to the question: Should code detect unexpected strings like `"dan 1 2 3 x`` or "joe bob 1 2 3"?  Or do you simply want an answers that assume the data in the strings well formed?

Comment: @RahulSinha: if you are going to edit 10 or more posts per hour, better make sure your edits are significant, rather than trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this never ends is because you are constantly providing the same string to scan.

`sscanf` provides the `%n` switch which stores the amount of characters read before it is reached inside a, which allows you to move forward in your input string by that amount of characters before rescanning.

This'll work:

```
int step[20];
int index=0;
int readLen;
while(sscanf(mystring,"%d%n", &step[index++], &readLen)>0) {
  mystring += readLen;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A working solution is given in the answer from sokkyoku.

**Another possibility** to read variable length lines is to use strtok like in the following code snippet:

```
int getlines (FILE *fin)
{
    int  nlines = 0;
    int  count  = 0;
    char line[BUFFSIZE]={0};
    char *p;

    if(NULL == fgets(buff, BUFFSIZE, fin))
        return -1;

    while(fgets(line, BUFFSIZE, fin) != NULL) {
        //Remove the '\n' or '\r' character
        line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;
        count = 0;
        printf("line[%d] = %s\n", nlines, line);
        for(p = line; (p = strtok(p, " \t")) != NULL; p = NULL) {
            printf("%s ", p);
            ++count;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        ++nlines;
    }

    return nlines;
}
```

**Explanation** of the above function `getlines`:

Each line in the file `fin` is read using `fgets` and stored in the variable `line`. 
Then each substring in `line` (separated by a white space or `\t` character) is extracted and the pointer to that substring stored in `p`, by means of the function `strtok` in the for loop (see for example this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927793/how-to-use-strtok) for further example on strtok).

The function then just print `p` but you can do everything with the substring here. 
I also count (`++count`) the number of items found in each line. At the end, the function `getline` count and returns the number of lines read.

Comment: Minor bits: 1) Why `'\n'` in `strtok(p, " \t\n")`?  `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;` insures there is no longer a `'\n'`.  2) "separated by a white space or \t \n character" is really "separated by a space or \t \n character".

Comment: @chux thanks, I added the `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0` later and didn't modify the strtok