# For loop does not parse ssv file properly

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a code which I adapted from one that parsed a csv file. I am currently trying store the values of a polynomial given by an ssv file (space separated file), which is given on the command line, into variables, which is not working.
My code is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        char file[50];
        char buf[100] = "";
        int coef = 0;
        int exp = 0;
        strcpy(file,argv[1]);
        FILE *fp = fopen (file, "a+"); //file
        while (fgets (buf, 100, fp)){
                char *token = strtok(buf, " "); //split line
                for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 2; cnt++){
                        printf("cnt = %d\n", cnt);
                        if(cnt = 0){
                                coef = atof(token);
                                printf("coef = %d\n",coef);
                                printf("token = %s\n", token);
                        }
                        if (cnt = 1){
                                exp = atof(token);
                                printf("coef = %d",exp);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

With an ssv file

```
1 3
```

However, when I run it, it outputs

```
cnt = 0
coef = 1cnt = 0
coef = 0 prompt-$
```

I don't understand why. In my head, it starts the for loop with cnt = 0, and it returns the first variable (i.e. 1), and then cnt would be incremented and should store the exponent (3). However, it loops without incrementing and i don't know why. Also, the coef variable print doesn't create a newline when I put \n at the end, so I think it's not even finishing the loop?

Can anybody help me fix this or give me an alternative solution?
I tried sscanf("%d %d", coef, exp) instead of a for loop, but it gives me a int/pointer casting error.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: `if (cnt = 0) { ...` looks wrong (and others).

Comment: How do you compile this stuff? There should be plenty of compiler warnings. Those warnings are errors in your case. Fix the code so that there won't be any warnings.

Comment: That's not the correct usage of `strtok`: the input buffer has to be passed only the first time; then NULL has to be passed. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18927793/11336762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(cnt = 0){}

if (cnt = 1){}
```

If you want to compare, use `==` instead of `=`.

Because your file is formatted, so you should use `fscanf` that is more simple.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        char file[50];
        int coef = 0;
        strcpy(file,argv[1]);
        FILE *fp = fopen (file, "a+");
        while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &coef) == 1){
            printf("coef = %d\n",coef);
        }

}
```

Result:

```
#cat text.txt
1 3
./test text.txt
coef = 1
coef = 3
```

One more thing, the  `atof()`  function  converts  the string to double, but you declare `exp` with `int` type. Using `atoi`, `strtol`, or `sscanf`, if you want to convert to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @pzaenger: once you enter the `for` loop, you print `cnt = 0`, then you *assign* `0` to `cnt` in the `if` guard. The expression results in `0`, so you don't enter. Afterwards, you *assign* `1` to `cnt` and the statement results in `1`, so you enter the block, printing `coef = 1` (with no newline). Then the iteration finishes and `cnt` gets incremented, turns `2` and the loop finishes. Now you run a second iteration of the `while` loop, reading nothing (you already consumed the input, you should be checking for `EOF`) from `fp` to `buf`, `strtok` should be returning `NULL` in that case. Passing `NULL` to `atof` is probably UB (I haven't found mention to behavior on `NULL` on the manpage on Mac), and in your case you're being lucky and it just returns `0`.

Long story short: equality comparison is done with the operator `==`. A single `=` sign is assignment, and aside from the obvious behavior that is changing the value of the left-hand operand, the expression's result is the value that is assigned, i.e, the right-hand operand and the new value of the left-hand operand.

Regarding `sscanf`, since it *stores* data extracted from the string to its arguments, you need to pass there *addresses* like this: `sscanf(%d %d, &coef, &token)`.